# Flipping an unfair coin twice with the same outcome

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose I flip an unfair coin, weighted such that it has a 75% chance to land on heads, twice. Given that it is the same result both times (both heads or both tails), what is the probability that the outcome was heads both times?

This is a fairly simple question, but I can't remember how to solve it (and others like it). I know that I can't simply find the probability of both flips being heads (which is .5625), so how do I go about solving this?

Comment: Use the definition of conditional probability: $\Pr(A\mid B) = \dfrac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$

Comment: Okay, how would I calculate Pr(A and B)? Is it just .75*.25? Sorry, haven't done stuff like this in a long time.

Comment: $A$ is the event that it is both heads.  $B$ is the event that both are the same (either both heads or both tails).  $A\cap B$ is the intersection of these and noting that both heads implies both same will simplify to both heads.  $0.75\cdot 0.75$.  While it may be the case that you often have one event as one coin and the other event as the other coin, that is not how this problem was worded.

Comment: So, if I am understanding correctly, Pr(A and B) = Pr(A)*Pr(B). If we were to divide that by Pr(B), the Pr(B) cancels out leaving us with Pr(A), which is both heads, which is .75*.75

Comment: No... $\Pr(A\cap B)$ is not equal to $\Pr(A)\cdot \Pr(B)$.  They are equal **only** when $A$ and $B$ are independent.  Here with $A$ the event that both are heads and $B$ the event that both are same, they are certainly not independent.  Result of first coin *is* independent of result of second coin, but again those are not $A$ and $B$ here.

Comment: Okay, maybe I worded the problem poorly. I think that the answer below is the right way to approach it, because the coin flips are supposed to be independent. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are four possible outcomes to two coin flips: HH, HT, TH, TT. Given that the same outcome happened twice, we are left with HH and TT. However, before removing HT and TH we will calculate the probabilities to get said rolls.

$$P(HH)=\alpha^2$$

$$P(HT)=\alpha(1-\alpha)$$

$$P(TH)=(1-\alpha)\alpha$$

$$P(TT)=(1-\alpha)^2$$

where in your case $\alpha=.75$

Now, to get the probabilities when we know that HT and TH weren't rolled, simply do

$$P(HH|HH\text{ or TT})=\frac{P(HH)}{P(HH)+P(TT)}=\frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha^2+(1-\alpha)^2}=\frac{9}{10}$$